# Is there a way to prefill the google autocomplete place?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

From the browser navigation, I am getting an address as object like :

```
"sender": {
        "name": "Mary Jane",
        "address": "Jalan Tekronat",
        "city": "LAKSI",
        "state": "Bangkok",
        "country": "Thailand",
        "email": "",
        "mobile": "1234567890",
        "postalcode":"10010",
        "formatedAddress":"G218 Rama I Road, Pathum Wan, Bangkok, Thailand",
        "countryShortName":"TH",
        "countrySearchShortName":"TH"
    },
```

Since I have the address, customer ask to prefill the details in the autocomplete component. how to do that? I coun't find a way to do this.

here is my component:

```
this.sender = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchSenderAddressRef.nativeElement, {
                types:["address"]
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(this.senderAddressAutoComplete, 'place_changed', function(value){
                var place = that.senderAddressAutoComplete.getPlace();
                var address = '';
                if (place.address_components) {
                    address = [
                      (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                      (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                      (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                    ].join(' ');

                    let getPostalCode = place.address_components.find( obj => obj.types.includes("postal_code") );
                    let getCountry = place.address_components.find( obj => obj.types.includes("country") );
                    let getCity = place.address_components.find( obj => obj.types.includes("locality") );
                    let getState = place.address_components.find( obj => obj.types.includes("administrative_area_level_2") );

                    that.sharableData.bd.shipment.sender.postalcode = getPostalCode && (getPostalCode.long_name || "");
                    that.sharableData.bd.shipment.sender.address = address || "";
                    that.sharableData.bd.shipment.sender.country = getCountry.long_name || "";
                    that.sharableData.bd.shipment.sender.state = getState && (getState.long_name || "");
                    that.sharableData.bd.shipment.sender.city = getCity && (getCity.long_name || "");
                    that.sharableData.bd.shipment.sender.formatedAddress = place.formatted_address || "";
                    that.sharableData.bd.shipment.sender.countryShortName = getCountry && (getCountry.short_name || "");

                    that.senderAddress.setValue(address);
                    that.sharedData.updateSharedQuoteDatas(that.sharableData);

                }
            })
```

any one help me?

Answer (score -4):

First of all you need to be specific about the frontend technology that you're using (React, Angular, etc).

Alas!

Well, the whole idea behind pre-filling an input based component like `Autocomplete` is that you have to `initialise the component` with the data.

Read about

1. How data binding works?
2. Learn how to initialise an input component with a certain value bind to it.

Comment: I din't ask the question to add the data to input field. I am taking about `autocomplete` component in google api address search